# Import File to CSS Document Not Working

Tags: html, css, image, file, path

I am trying to import a picture that i want to use as a header for a website that i am currently building. I want to import the .png image onto the CSS file. I have done EXTENSIVE research into trying to figure out the problem i am currently having. The file path is correct everything is spelled correctly (Literally quadruple checked, maybe more) and i am still having a problem. I tried putting the ".." in front of the path and it was to no avail. The picture will be used as a banner for the top of the website. Here is all of my code. Kinda just started this website so there is not a whole lot.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
<title>Bludmon88-NAVBAR</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "Styles.css">
<ul class = "navigation">
<li><a href = "index.html">Home</a>
<li><a href = "index.html">Home</a>
<li><a href = "index.html">Home</a>
<li><a href = "index.html">Home</a>
</ul>
</div>
<div class = "banner">
<div class = "title">

</div>
</div>
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.navigation a, li{
list-style:none;
display:inline-block;
float:left;
padding:3px 50px 1px 0px;
text-decoration:none;
font-size:20px;
}
.banner {
background-image: url('/F:/Bludmon88/Pics/Banner.png'); 

}
```

P.S Not extremely knowledgeable about HTML and CSS but got the basics and i will have no idea what you are talking about if you bring up other languages so... ya. Thanks!

Comment: I think that you need to avoid using **absolute paths**, you need to use a relative path like /Pics/Banner.png

Comment: for a test insert your paht (e.g. http://localhost/Bludmon88/Pics/Banner.png) to your browser and see if the pic is present. If so take that link to your CSS. Test your page. Then make the link relative removing the http: and the spear /

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mention height or if no content in div then background image will not display . add bellow css then it will display

```
.banner {
            background-image: url('http://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.M831bc7403efb71bfe938858406d2d01cH0&pid=15.1');
            height: 300px;
            width: 100%;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a "images" folder within your main folder and keep that banner image within it. Then set the background url to work properly in your local site as well as server:

```
.banner {
  background-image: url('images/Banner.png'); 
}
```